# Promise chain fundamental issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to understand Promises. I've create some promise chains that work and others that don't. I've made progress but am apparently lacking a basic concept. For example, the following promise chain doesn't work. It's a silly example, but shows the issue; I'm trying to use Node's function randomBytes twice in a chain:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var randomBytes = Promise.promisify(require("crypto").randomBytes);

randomBytes(32)
.then(function(bytes) {
    if (bytes.toString('base64').charAt(0)=== 'F') {
        return 64;   //if starts with F we want a 64 byte random next time
    } else {
        return 32;
    }
})
.then(randomBytes(input))
.then(function(newbytes) {console.log('newbytes: ' + newbytes.toString('base64'));})
```

The error that arrises here is "`input` is undefined." Am I trying to do something that can't (or shouldn't) be done?

Comment: Error seems clear... Where is `input` defined?

Comment: You probably needs to pass `.then(randomBytes)` instead.

Comment: Ugg. I see. (red faced)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always need to pass a callback *function* to `then()`. It will be called with the result of the promise that you attach it to.

You're currently calling `randomBytes(input)` immediately, which (if `input` was defined) would have passed a promise. You need to pass a function expression that just *gets* the `input` as its parameter:

```
.then(function(input) {
    return randomBytes(input);
});
```

Or just pass the function itself directly:

```
randomBytes(32)
.then(function(bytes) {
    return (bytes.toString('base64').charAt(0)=== 'F') ? 64 : 32;
})
.then(randomBytes)
.then(function(newbytes) {
    console.log('newbytes: ' + newbytes.toString('base64'));
});
```