# How to make call to a JavaScript promise cleaner?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following call to a Javascript promise:

```
deleteDatabase().then(function () {
    doSomeStuff();
}, function (err) {
    processError(err);
});
```

It works fine, but it looks really wordy.  Is there a way to have a terser way to do this?  Maybe something like this (which does not seem to work):

```
deleteDatabase().then(doSomeStuff(), processError(err));
```

Comment: Don't call the functions, just pass them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Promise chain fundamental issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25431919/1048572) and a few others

Comment: FYI, arguments are always evaluated first. So if you have `foo(bar(baz));`, then `bar` is called first with the value of `baz` and then `foo` is called with the return value of `bar`. JavaScript may have its quirks, but this evaluation works like most other languages.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a *function*, not the result of calling them:

```
deleteDatabase().then(doSomeStuff, processError);
```

Of course, this will pass the result of the `deleteDatabase()` action to your `doSomeStuff` function, so if you expect it to get no arguments you will need to use the function expression as you did.

Comment: So the function parameter `err` will just automatically get passed to `processError`?

Comment: `then` passes an error object to the second function. Whether that is your function expression with the `err` parameter or the `processError` function doesn't make a difference to it.

Comment: you can also snuff out unwanted arguments via bind: .then(doSomeStuff.bind(this,undefined));

Comment: No, the parameter passed via the promise chain will be *additional* to any established with `.bind()`. The only way to "snuff out" such a parameter is to ignore it inside the `.then()` callback. In your example, `undefined` (or anything else) will not magically mask the parameter passed by promise.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: dandavis means that when the function expects only one argument, you can "shift out" the result by binding `undefined`. Doesn't work for everything of course, and is quite questionable IMO.

Comment: Ah OK, "shift out" explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with the syntax

`deleteDatabase().then(doSomeStuff, processError);`

if you put `()` after the function name it will call it immediately, by omitting the parenthesis you are passing a reference to the function and asking for it to be called at some point later on by the promise.